# Symfony error DoctrineMigrationsBundle requires DoctrineBundle to be enabled

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am starting to use Symfony migrations into existing Symfony applications. As mentioned in the documentation I started by installing `orm-pack` as follows

`https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html`

This command installed following packages as can be seen from `composer.json` file

```
"doctrine/orm"
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.10"
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3"
```

but the command ended up with following error

[image]

and after that when I tried to check the status of migration as follows

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status
```

I again get the same error that is
`DoctrineMigrationsBundle requires DoctrineBundle to be enabled.`

For the reference, this is my `doctrine_migrations.yaml` file

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'App\Migrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'

    # Connection to use for the migrations
    connection: default

    storage:
        # Default (SQL table) metadata storage configuration
        table_storage:
                table_name: 'doctrine_migration_versions'
                version_column_name: 'version'
                version_column_length: 192
                executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'

    # Possible values: "BY_YEAR", "BY_YEAR_AND_MONTH", false
    organize_migrations: false

    # Path to your custom migrations template
    custom_template: ~

    # Run all migrations in a transaction.
    all_or_nothing: false

    # Adds an extra check in the generated migrations to ensure that is executed on the same database type.
    check_database_platform: true

    # Whether or not to wrap migrations in a single transaction.
    transactional: true
```

I am not really sure what went wrong.

Update

I have added following line in `bundles.php` file

`Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],`

Comment: I have the same issue after installing a 5.2 Symfony project.

Comment: did you fix this? how please???